# Using mercurial's mq for managing local changes

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

I have a local mercurial repository with some site-specific changes in it.  What I would like to do is set a couple files to be un-commitable so that they aren't automatically committed when I do an `hg commit` with no arguments.

Right now, I'm doing complicated things with `mq` and guards to achieve this, pushing and popping and selecting guards to prevent my changes (which are checked into an mq patch) from getting committed.

Is there an easier way to do this?  I'm sick of reading the help for all the `mq` commands every time I want to commit a change that doesn't include my site-specific changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that bazaar has shelve and unshelve commands to push and pop changes you don't want included in a commit.  I think it's pretty likely that Mercurial has similar commands.

Comment: Thank you!  That's exactly what I needed.  Here's a link to the extension:

http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/index.cgi/ShelveExtension

Answer (score 2):

I would put those files in `.hgignore` and commit a "sample" form of those files so that they could be easily recreated for a new site when someone checks out your code.

Comment: I think that would only work if I had control of the upstream repository.  However, adding them to .hgignore anyway might still work...  It's still not ideal, though.  Maybe the answer is to just have scripts that patch and unpatch the files in question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why you can't have another repo checked out with those specific changes, and then transplant/pull/patch to it when you need to update stuff. Then you'd be primarily working from the original repo, and it's not like you'd be wasting space since hg uses links. I commonly have two+ versions checked out so I can work on a number of updates then merge them together.